# boolean loop & switch statement

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean, switch-statement, logical-operators

I am trying to validate that the user has entered in a correct char. I am assuming that a char has been entered.

Problem: When I first type in say "f", the carSize is returned and everything works fine and the code moves on correctly. If I type in say "d" first, "You have not entered in a correct value..." is displayed correctly, but then when I enter in a correct value such as "f" again, it just keeps repeating "You have not entered in a correct value" and waits for another response. After that point, no matter what is entered it will spit that back message as if the answer is incorrect. This is fairly simple and I cant for the life of me figure out what the frick I am doing wrong. I am a beginner, so maybe I am using "size" incorrectly in the function? Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
const string RENTAL_DAYS = "Enter number of days rented: ";

cout << RENTAL_DAYS;
        cin >> rentalDays;
        rentalDays = correctNumberCheck(rentalDays, RENTAL_DAYS);


    char rentalSizeCheck(char size, string question) {

             bool notValid = true;
             size = toupper(size);

                     while(notValid) {  

                       switch (size) {

                           case 'C':
                                notValid = false;
                                break;
                           case 'M':
                                notValid = false;
                                break;
                           case 'F':
                                notValid = false;
                                break;
                           case 'S':
                                notValid = false;
                                break;
                           default:
                                cout << "You have not entered in a correct value " 
                                        << ", please try again" << endl;
                                cout << question;
                                cin >> size;
                              }// Close switch
                     } // Close while loop
             return carSize;
             }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling toupper() outside of the loop, so the second time you get your input, it's still lower case and doesn't catch any of the conditions in the loop.

Comment: +1, that's a good point, but how the first `f` was uppercased?

Comment: Your right. Thanks for the help. I'll use a dowhile loop instead so that way it toupper will always be called first. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
```

before reading from cin to ignore any wandering ENTERs. Otherwise these enters will be read instead of the char you enter.

Comment: Good catch, see my point below, I think there are actually 2 bugs in here ;)

Comment: No. They are whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char rentalSizeCheck(char size, string question) {
  bool notValid = true;

  while (notValid) {
    size = toupper(size);
    switch (size) {
    case 'C':
    case 'M':
    case 'F':
    case 'S':
      notValid = false; break;
    default:
      cout << "You have not entered in a correct value "
           << ", please try again" << endl;
      cout << question;
      cin >> size;
    }
  }
  return size;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << rentalSizeCheck(' ', "CMFS> ");
}
```